# How to get the Terminal in Visual Studio 2019 to respect system keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've been using the built-in Terminal in Visual Studio 2019.  It works great, however, it doesn't respect Ctrl+C for clipboard copy.

Typing Ctrl+C results in ^C appearing on the command line.  As it stands the only way to copy things out of the terminal is to highlight it with the mouse, then right-click.  That puts it on the clipboard.

How can I get it to respect the system shortcut?